# Is it possible in PhpStorm to automatically change namespaces and uses according to a changed project folder structure?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I've got to a point where I need to change my project folder structure. When I'll do so, some namespaces will change and after, some `use` statements will need to be different.

So I'm wondering if there is a way (maybe PhpStorm has some functionality for it) to handle changed namespaces and `use` statements automatically?

Comment: Use `Refactor | Move` or `Refactor | Rename` on a class or namespace (it's context dependant). It will apply changes where it sees the references to the affected class(es).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no feature like the one you ask for, for as far as I'm aware. You can however use the following method for the use statements:

Use `CTRL + SHIFT + R (Replace in path)` to replace the old use statements throughout your whole project with the updated statement.

This just leaves renaming the namespaces, which you'll have to do yourself.

Comment: At least I won't need to change all the uses manually. Namespaces are the easier part. Thanks!

Comment: If you've declared the source root as PSR-0 root in PhpStorm, you can use `Refactor | Move` and PhpStorm will automatically update the namespace declarations of everything, inclusing `use` statements

Answer (score 3):

you can use `refactor` if I understood correctly what you want:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/move-namespace-dialog.html